# can't get current fragment by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a problem to get current fragment by id 
after replacing fragment with tag 
when trying to get the same fragment i found it null

```
       FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.request_frame, requestFragment, "Confirm").commit();
    RequestFragment requestFragment1=(RequestFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Confirm");
    if (null!=requestFragment1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "framgent found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "framgent Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

so always received fragment not found

Comment: Try to replace `commit()` with `commitNow()`

Comment: Did replacing the fragment after creating the `requestFragment`? Please include the code where you're creating the `requestFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.YOUR_CONTAINER);

if (fragment != null && fragment.equals(RequestFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
    RequestFragment requestFragment1 = (RequestFragment) fragment;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "framgent found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "framgent Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```